# Can we burn comparative christianity?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed today that we have a tag: [comparative-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-christianity).

This seems like a tag that's just begging for terrible questions. Is there a good reason to have it?

Comment: I don't even know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping it is alright only because a question that would like two  denominational positions that confusingly 'use the same words' with almost opposing meanings... unraveled, might not be able to chose another tag. At least I can't think of another tag. Maybe there is an alternate that carries a compare or contrast the similarities and differences sort of Q & A?

It could also be used to get a comparative explanation on splinter groups that seem exactly the same to an outsider but actually hang huge key differences on a nuance over a single word.

I would not use it a lot but it does seem to fit a niche market.

Comment: My problem isn't the question type necessarily, though in general the questions of this type aren't very good (gorilla vs shark is kind of relevant here). The problem is that it's  a meta tag to some degree or another

Comment: @waxeagle - even though I argued a case for it, I don't think anybody would notice if it disapeared.

Answer (score -3):

Well, that would be a decidedly view-point un-neutral take on the direction this site is supposed to take.

If you ban the tag, that means we should be closing questions like [the one discussed at length here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/prominent-theologian-best-question-evah-and-or-gross-moderator-oversight-f), right?

Comment: No. For one thing, banning the tag doesn't ban the question type. wrt to questions like that it's at best a meta tag. At worst it signifies a question with scoping issues

Comment: @PeterTurner, did I see you quote Martin Luther King, Jr., in an answer/comment to a question asking for information from an Orthodox perspective?  I'm just trying to see exactly what your vision is for denomination tagging / un-neutralness / walled gardens.

Comment: @pterandon to be fair, Martin Luther King, Jr was quoting St. Augustine